# Dynamic and changing XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am writing a script to navigate a web page using selenium. I usually just find and select all elements based on XPATH. However, one of the elements xpath's appears to be changing slightly every week or so. How can I select or find this element without being subject to the dynamic XPATH?

Here is how I currently select element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="footable_213701"]/tfoot/tr/td/div/ul/li[15]/a')
```

Here is the element and attributes

```
<li class="footable-page-nav" data-page="next">
<a class="footable-page-link" href="#">></a>
</li>
```

I'm needing to select the ">" button to navigate to next page. I cannot select by class="footable-page-link" because there are a dynamic number of those so I don't know which one to select.

Comment: Does this id changes @id="footable_213701 ?

Comment: The joys of screen-scraping. If there's some rule you can give us that tells you where to find the required data, then we can help you translate that rule into XPath. If there's no such rule, then we can't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of ways you can try it in xpath,

1) Click on the anchor based on data-page - Next

```
//li[@data-page="next"]/a
```

2) Click on '>' using that as a text,

```
//li[@class="footable-page-nav"]/a[contains(.,'>')]
```

or simply,

```
//a[contains(.,'>')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to write XPATH is to avoid using numeric values (i.e id's with numeric values) which means they are dynamic in nature and `li[15]` here you are referencing the 15th list item which may change due to addition or deletion of an item, which will fail your XPATH.

try below,

```
driver.findElement(By.XPATH("//li[@class='footable-page-nav']/a"));
```

Thank You,

Comment: There are two XPATH's that go by this. How am I able to get the second or nth interation? This is working except for that.

Comment: When your XPATH has 2 matching nodes, try to derive it from root of the page/section/popup.I have faced same issue in my project, derived the XPATH as below. Hope it helps. //ul[@class='menucontainer']//li[@class='subsectionnode']//div[@class='popoutmenu']//li[@path='/Dxxx/xxxx']/a